# Приложение зависло на обработке обновления в Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Всем привет!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Обычно обновления для приложения обрабатывалось в течении двух часов.Но тут в течении  не было ни каких изменений.Я решил загрузить другую версию,после около 20 часов появилось предупреждение [image: появилось предупреждение], которое как по мне не сильно влияет на процесс обновления приложения. Сейчас прошло более 40 часов никаких действий я больше не принимал. Подскажите нормально ли это и что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас обновления могут обрабатываться до 3х дней. 
https://www.choiceofgames.com/2019/08/google-warns-developers-that-all-new-apps-require-three-days-for-approval/